# How to identify certain QGraphicItems in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have several `QGraphicItems` in a `QGraphicsScene`.
I want to modify only some of them when the `QGraphicsView` containing the scene gets resized.
The reason is that I have painted a grid respective to the view.

So how can I identify the items making up the grid in a `QGraphivcsView::resizeEvent()`?

Would it be possible to adjust the scene in a way that a given area (sceneRect) is always filling the complete view?

Comment: For your last question you might be able to do it with `QGraphicsView::scale` if you know the new size and the old size which seems possible with: `QResizeEvent::oldSize()`

For the rest I don't really understand, can't you use the *QGraphicsItem ?

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I identify the items making up the grid in a QGraphivcsView::resizeEvent()?

One way would be to simply use `dynamic_cast` and `QGrahpicsScene::items()`:

```
foreach( QGraphicsItem *item, myScene->items() )
{
  GridItem *gridItem = dynamic_cast<GridItem*>( item );
  if( gridItem )
  {
    // Apply appropriate transformation here
  }
}
```

A slightly more "Qt" way to do the above would be to ensure your QGraphicsItem subclass reimplements [QGraphicsItem::type()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type)

```
foreach( QGraphicsItem *item, myScene->items() )
{
  if( item->type() == GridItem::Type )
  {
    // Apply appropriate transformation here
  }
}
```

> Would it be possible to adjust the scene in a way that a given area
>   (sceneRect) is always filling the complete view?

[QGraphicsView::fitInView()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) should do the trick

Also, while I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, it sounds to me that you may want to check out the `QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag.

```
myItem->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIgnoresTransformations )
```

which makes it so that any item with the given flag will not be affected by changes in the zoom level.